# detect camera type in getMediaStream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Is there any way to detect whether the user has a front, rear, or both cameras in their device? For example, on a laptop, we normally have just one user camera, and it doesn't have a rear camera. On a device, it may have both cameras, and I want a way to detect the user camera type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whether a user's device has a front, rear, or both types of cameras using the MediaDevices API.

**[Example from mdn:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)**

```
if (!navigator.mediaDevices?.enumerateDevices) {
  console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
} else {
  // List cameras and microphones.
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .enumerateDevices()
    .then((devices) => {
      devices.forEach((device) => {
        console.log(`${device.kind}: ${device.label} id = ${device.deviceId}`);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

```
.then(devices => {
    const cameras = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');

    if (cameras.length === 0) {
        console.log('No cameras found');

    } else if (cameras.length === 1) {
        console.log('camera found');

        console.log('Camera label:', cameras[0].label);

    } else {
        console.log(' cameras found');

        console.log(' camera label:', cameras[0].label);

        console.log('Rear camera label:', cameras[1].label);

    }
})
.catch(err => console.error('Error accessing media devices:', err));
```